# How to purge day-based log files at Windows in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

As title, the log file was generated daily named as xxxx-yyyy-mmdd.txt. I hope a log file will be deleted once it's older than one month. That's, the file, xxxx--dd.txt will be removed at day -<mm+1>-dd. Is there any easy way to do such a task or resource to be leverage to save my time of writing tens of line codes?

Comment: It should be quite easy to list all the files and parse the file name. As you said, less than hundred lines of code when you leverage all possibilities of the standard library. I doubt that such a very specific utility would exist and think that writing some code would be faster.

Comment: Try googling for: windows batch delete files older than a month.

Comment: Do you need **exactly** one month, varying with the month length? Because it's easy to get a list of filenames, sort them alphabetically, remove the last 31 from the list, and then delete all remaining filenames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment points out, there are several steps:

1. filter the file with the name pattern
2. parse the file name into date and compare it with the current date
3. schedule to delete the target files in a parallel way.

File system access is slow, run the deletion in a parallel way will make it faster than a single thread.

Note the code needs c++17 to compile:

```cpp
#include <regex>
#include <filesystem>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <execution>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;
void remove_old_files(const std::regex& re, const std::string& dir,
                      size_t ndays) {
  std::time_t now =
      std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(std::chrono::system_clock::now());

  std::vector<fs::path> delayed_remove;
  for (const auto& entry : fs::recursive_directory_iterator(dir)) {
    std::smatch result;
    const std::string& name = entry.path().filename().string();
    if (std::regex_match(name, result, re)) {
      assert(result.size() >= 4);
      std::tm tm{};

      tm.tm_year = std::stoi(result[1].str()) - 1900;
      tm.tm_mon = std::stoi(result[2].str()) - 1;
      tm.tm_mday = std::stoi(result[3].str());
      std::time_t file_date = std::mktime(&tm);

      if (file_date < now && now - file_date > ndays * 86400) {
        std::cerr << "sheduled to erase:" << entry.path() << '\n';
        delayed_remove.push_back(entry.path());
      }
    }
  }
  std::for_each(std::execution::par, delayed_remove.begin(),
                delayed_remove.end(), [](const auto& p) { fs::remove(p); });
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  constexpr size_t ndays = 1;
  std::regex re{R"(.{4}-(\d{4})-(\d{2})(\d{2}))"};
  remove_old_files(re, ".", ndays);
  return 0;
}
```

[Online demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hnefx5bGz)

Comment: I got error at "namespace fs = std::filesystem;" and passed after I changed it to "namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;"
But I still got trouble at line "fs::recursive_directory_iterator(dir)" for it's not member of it. Could you tell me why?

Comment: @StanHuangatTaiwan What's your compiler's version, have you enabled the c++17 flags? If you have enabled c++17, then your compiler's version is too old and needs to be upgraded. Or we can use the boost library instead of a workaround.

Comment: To enable c++17: project properities-> C/C++ -> Language -> C++ language standard

Comment: I enabled c++2017 and it's much better, but I still got the following errors at the line containing "entry.path().filesystem":

1. C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'std::filesystem::path' to 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>' 

2.  E0312 no suitable user-defined conversion from "std::filesystem::path" to "std::string" exists

Comment: @StanHuangatTaiwan I have fixed it: `const std::string& name = entry.path().filename().string();`

Comment: @StanHuangatTaiwan Any update on this problem, I think it would be fine now.

Comment: I tested it successfully except that "(.{4}-(\d{4})-(\d{2})(\d{2}))" is needed to modify. I hope any prefix before yyyy-mmdd and extension of ".txt".
I am not familiar with C++ regular expression, so I'm still in fixing it. Basically, your codes are almost perfect. I will adopt it. Thanks.

Comment: @StanHuangatTaiwan You can try to build your own regex with the help of this site: https://regex101.com/, it's awesome and makes it much easier to build regex and test it.